# remove 'WWW' in ASP.NET MVC 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I am attempting to force the domain name to not use the 'www'. I want to redirect the user if attempted. I have seen very little on an MVC solution. Is there anyway to harness the routing built into MVC, or what the best solutions is.

Thanks

Comment: Are you on Apache, IIS 6, or IIS 7?

Comment: IIS7, see reply on your post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the server, you should set up a virtual directory that accepts requests for "www.example.com" and permanently redirects (301) them to "example.com"

While this may be *possible* in ASP.NET MVC, it is not ASP's job to do this sort of redirecting.

On IIS:
[image: Virtual Directory]

On Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Both the IIS and the Apache settings will preserve the URL stem.

Comment: Can you do this while preserving the users url. I want to drop the www transparently to the user, not just kick them back to root.

Comment: @durilai: If you use the settings in the screen shot I just added, you will get exactly that effect.  This is how I have my server configured.  For example, try going to http://www.lanlordz.com/Forums/

Comment: I use discountasp.net, while they allow connecting to IIS manager I am unable to modify this. I would prefer this method, but do not think it is possible on shared host. Any thoughts?

Comment: In IIS this just adds some line to the web.config, you don't need access to the admin tool to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Implemented as an ActionFilter as that is MVC-like, and more explicit.

```
public class RemoveWwwFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;


        var host = req.Uri.Host.ToLower();
        if (host.StartsWith("www.")) {
            var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url) {
                Host = host.Substring(4);
            };
            res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Apply the ActionFilter to your controllers, or your base controller class if you have one.

For an introduction to Action Filters, see [Understanding Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-14-cs.aspx) on MSDN.

```
[RemoveWwwFilterAttribute]
public class MyBaseController : Controller
```

Comment: This will modify all request including script and stylesheet files, is there a way to just capture the views.

Comment: Why don't you use a `UriBuilder` for this, and use Request.Url?

Comment: @John Agreed, that is is a better approach.

Comment: Not sure the UriBuilder solves my initial problem with this method. Am I missing something?

Comment: @durilai ActionFilters apply only to those actions or controllers that you apply them to (they are Attributes).

Comment: I have seen attribute method, but I feel it is not really the best solution. I would hate to have to add an attribute to every controller, not that it is difficult but I tend to side with the DRY methodology. I have found a decent solution in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DustinLaine: that's why Lachlan said just add that attribute to your controller baseclass

Answer (score 3):

Although I believe [John Gietzen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57986/john-gietzen) answer is the most elegant solution, I was unable to implement do to a shared hosting environment. Determined to find a non-application driven solution I found this [blog post](http://nayyeri.net/remove-www-prefix-from-urls-with-url-rewrite-module-for-iis-7-0) which shows a good alternative method for IIS7. Thankfully DiscountASP.NET's has the URL Rewrite module available through the IIS Manager tool.

Following this blog post on creating a rewrite rule any URL with www in the domain will do a permanent 301 redirect to the non-www site. All while preserving the full paths.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 2):

This is more generic configuration as you can write it once in the URL Rewrite of the root IIS (not specific to a certain application pool) and it will automatically be applied to ALL your IIS websites without any dependency on your domain name.

[image: IIS Remove WWW]