# How does one eliminate the "www." at the beginning of urls at the server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Poorly worded title, but what I want is to do essentially what StackOverflow does when someone types in `www.stackoverflow.com`: it redirects immediately to `stackoverflow.com`, eliminating the `www.` entirely.

Imo, this is the more modern way of doing things: the `www.` is redundant and (soon to be) archaic. It also breaks an important principle that I want to follow on my web application: that each unique and valid page be accessible by a single url only.

I realize this is a server thing, so I'm expecting the answer to be that the web host needs to take care of this. Since I don't run my own servers, my question is thus: is this possible to do on shared hosting or does one need to be running a dedicated server in order to configure IIS to do this?

Comment: “the www. is redundant” — potentially, although it can still be a useful way to distinguish services to avoid cookie issues. For example, if you set a cookie for stackoverflow.com, that cookie would be included with all requests to *.stackoverflow.com, including e.g. image requests, where cookies are unnecessary. If SO’s CDN was at cdn.stackoverflow.com, that would be a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove 'WWW' in ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256353/remove-www-in-asp-net-mvc-1-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IIS URL Rewriter will allow you to easily set up a canonoical domain rule so all requests are either redirected to www or non www based on your choice. [More info on how](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/)

Also, several .net shared hosting providers have this module installed so that you can configure this option like you could on your own iis server.

Comment: Can this sort of thing be done on shared hosting though? Or do I need complete control over the server?

Comment: Some .net shared hosting providers have this module installed - its a fairly common module now.

Answer (score 3):

`www.` is not redundant or archaic if you are using other subdomains.  There are issues with cookies that you have to deal with if you set `stackoverflow.com` as the root domain.

That being said, you would probably want to do something like my answer to a previous question here:

[remove 'WWW' in ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256353/remove-www-in-asp-net-mvc-1-0/2256362#2256362)

Based on the similarities to this question, and based on your tags, I'm voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the bit about cookies in mind, and research it further.

Answer (score 1):

Most hosting providers give this for free. The trick itself is usually performed on the DNS level, by introducing a no-hostname A record in your domain.

And this principle of yours is unattainable in principle. At the very least, there's always the URL with IP address instead of name. Then, your server will, most likely, have a private name like server1334.hostingprovider.com, which is also accessible to the world.

Comment: Yes that's true. I guess the traditional "www." way of doing things doesn't really break it so much, but I still want to get rid of it and at the same time not break the rule in doing so: so long as all links point to "domain.com" without the "www." I consider that acceptable.

Comment: It's up to you whether to advertise it with www. or without. But setting up a site deliberately without www. would be simply silly - you'd lose some visitors on that.

Comment: For clarification, I still want urls entered with "www." to redirect to the appropriate page (in effect breaking my rule as I stated it). You're right it would be silly to simply not work for those urls. What I really meant is that nowhere on the site should there ever be an internal link that starts with "www.".

Comment: Internal links usually don't have a hostname to begin with. Unless it's a multihost site (static content hosted separately, or something like that),.all HTML should be root URL-agnostic. Testing will be much easier, too.

Comment: Right, good point, hence why the redirect is what's most important here.